# DevExpress deployed application looking for dxicons

Tags: devexpress

I am consolidating a few DevExpress dashboards into a single project. They were originally done in separate projects prototyping and demonstration purposes. When running them in a new project (which is a new IIS application), they are requesting icons/dxicons.woff and then when that fails with a 404 error, icons/dxicons.ttf is requested. I understand that the woff is a compressed ttf file so it makes sense its falling back to request the ttf file.

Am I missing a handler to serve up the icons? The icons folder doesn't exists in the original projects.

Answer (score 1):

We need add this in configuration of build to load the .woff/.tff font files. I am not sure which framework you used.
    I faced same issue in my angular seed application. I fixed this issue by adding the source and destination paths of  icons/dxicons.ttf.
    Please find the below fix and see whether it may helps you to find any way in your application

tools/config/project.config.ts

```
ICONS_DEST = `${this.CSS_DEST}/icons`;
  ICONS_SRC = [
      'node_modules/devextreme/dist/css/icons/**'
  ];
```

tools/tasks/project/build.fonts.ts

```
export = () => {
        var paths = [
            { src: Config.FONTS_SRC, dest: Config.FONTS_DEST },
            { src: Config.ICONS_SRC, dest: Config.ICONS_DEST }
        ];
        var tasks = paths.map(function(path) {
            return gulp.src(path.src).pipe(gulp.dest(path.dest));
        });
        return tasks;
    };
```

It loads the dxicons.ttf to my dist folder, I deployed to server and working as expected.